# Why does my soufflé collapse in the oven?

Tags: eggs, egg-whites, meringue, souffle

I have now tried to make Bobby Flay's blackberry souffle twice, and both times, after initially rising beautifully, it collapsed completely while still in the oven. The results were inedible.

Does anyone have any idea how to prevent this disaster should I be brave enough to try this recipe a third time?

Comment: Did you open the oven door at any point?

Comment: I don't think it's related, but try and use a thermometer to make sure your oven is as hot as you want it to.

Comment: I didn't open door at any point during the cooking process. The souffles just fell :-( after about 20-23 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Johnny... great idea to verify the oven temp for alot of reasons. I'll give it try

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure your souffle has an even cooking temperature.

1) dont open the door to the oven

2) make sure your oven tempature doesnt fluctuate widley

3) put the souffle inside a small pool of water. This helps to regulate the temperature better.